# Failed to load resource: 404 not fount - javascript plugin for theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, responsive-design, http-status-code-404

I am trying to implement a plugin from

http://responsive-nav.com

I tried to put it in my custom theme which I am currently developing on my MAMP local server

I created a folder in my theme directory called "responsive-nav" and inside it I put the init-js file also the responsive-nav.css and the responsive-nav.js

in order to call all three of those files, I put this code in my functions.php

```
function aspect_responsive_nav() {
wp_enqueue_style(  'responsive-nav-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/responsive-nav/responsive-nav.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-nav-js',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/responsive-nav/responsive-nav.js', array(), '1.0.25', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-nav-js-init',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/responsive-nav/responsive-nav-init.js', array(), false, true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aspect_responsive_nav' );
```

However, in my web console it gives me a 404 not found and the plugin doesn't work right...
any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What directory does get_template_directory_uri() point to?

Comment: it points to a folder in my theme named 'responsive-nav' and includes those 3 files which doesn't seem to work

Comment: If that points to a folder named responsive-nav, then I believe you are trying to access the files at ./responsive-nav/responsive-nav/whatever.js. Try removing ./responsive-nav/ and just use ./

Comment: it still doesn't load properly

Comment: If you view source of the page is the path to the files being included correct?